# How do make an automatic cropping for the interest area in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm the beginner of image processing by using MATLAB and i have to do some tasks, i want to crop or cut for the specific area like using imcrop but want to make it automatic (i cannot upload picture because i'm the new user, the picture that i use is the cross-section of a plant) i really don't know how to detect and cut out only that area. I'll really appreciate if there's someone can help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use an image uploader like [imgur](http://imgur.com) to link to images. You should also add [what you have already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Can you define more accurately what you mean by the region of interest?

Comment: Thank you so much.i had upload my image and here is the link http://postimage.org/image/l09f8ms4j/ I want to crop only the red rectangle area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us more information. If you want to automate the detection of a part of an image to crop it, you need to do some image processing. What kind will depend on the characteristics of your images and the part you want to crop.

You can post an image using, for example, http://www.postimage.org/

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to make an auto crop of the area of the red rectangle. Here is the link of my image http://postimage.org/image/l09f8ms4j/